# Css Animations w/ Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, 3d

I've been at this for hours, I've checked all over the web and I've found things that have helped, but I can't seem to get the result I'm after.

I'm trying to make a simple game using css animations. I've split the the screen into 9 equal divs in rows of 3. I want you to start in the center block and when you click a button in another div your "ship" goes to that div and stays there until another button is clicked.

I've managed to get the ship to move however, when I try to add rotation to it to give it a "roll" effect of an actual plane, it dive bombs through the animation on the set rotation degree. I want the game to scroll along z-axis for a pseudo-3D look. kind of like the old top down vertical scrolling shooters except 3D-ish.

```
animation-name : cssAnimation;
   animation-duration : 1s;
   animation-iteration-count : 1;
   animation-timing-function : ease;
   animation-fill-mode :;
   -webkit-animation-name : cssAnimation;
   -webkit-animation-duration : 1s;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count : 1;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function : ease;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode :;
   -ms-animation-name : cssAnimation;
   -ms-animation-duration : 1s;
   -ms-animation-iteration-count : 1;
   -ms-animation-timing-function : ease;
   -ms-animation-fill-mode :;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
   0% {
       -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translateX(0%);
   }
   75% {
       -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translateX(-225%);
   }
   100% {
       -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translateX(-225%);
   }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanhagz/5GAX7/

Comment: You had some errors before, which I fixed by editing your listeners and putting them into jQuery, check out my fiddle to see what I did (http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/5GAX7/8/). What is supposed to happen exactly, because the only thing that happens for me is that the ship moves from the middle left box to the center box.

Comment: yeah I updated the rotation for a min. I've change it back to the original 15 deg. I want it to go straight across to the midleft or midright boxes at a 15 degree angle without diving down and level out again as the animation ends & I want the animations to be triggered by clicking. I think what I need to do is make two separate animations, one for the rotation and one for the position change and put a small delay on the rotation so it gives it the "roll" look. idk though, I've been using XHTML & CSS for years, but virtually new to the whole css3 animations concept. :P

Comment: If you can draw a picture of what you want for the animation, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: A good example of the effect I'm after is the first half of the animation at the top of this page: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

The only differences are I don't want the second half spinning back and I'd like the intital rotation to be done over the course of the horizontal movement starting at obviously 0deg then to roughly 15deg and back to 0deg as it "lands" in the specific div button chosen.

Comment: Is this the effect you are going for? http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/5GAX7/34/ Just click the run button after it loads so you can see the animation from start to finish.

Comment: Yeah actually! only thing was I need it at -15deg not 15, but i fixed it:)

I was wondering though, like I said above, is there a way i could delay or offset the rotation by about .2 - .3 sec. so it looks like the ship starts to move before the rotation occurs or would I have to use the "steps" method for that?

Comment: It looks very strange, the only way to delay it would be to set it to `translateX` before it finishes `rotate` in the animation definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is actually change around your timings and rules in the animation definitions. First of all, if a property is not changed in the animation, it is not necessary to declare it, so properties such as `skew` and `scale` can be left out in the definition.

Additionally, the code you have should be re-arranged to:

```
-webkit-animation: cssAnimation 1s cubic-bezier(.13,.38,.12,.97);
-ms-animation: cssAnimation 1s cubic-bezier(.13,.38,.12,.97);
animation: cssAnimation 1s cubic-bezier(.13,.38,.12,.97);
```

In the code, I took away the undeclared rules (`fill-mode`) and the rules that you had the default number. which is 1 by the way for `iteration-count`. Lastly I reordered them, because the unprefixed should be last. If you weren't aware, most browsers parse the CSS in such a way that the last rule that they can interpret will be the rule that they will obey. For example, in Google Chrome 29, the unprefixed version may work and will be the one to use because it is the standard, but since you had the `-webkit-` CSS after, the Chrome parser will use `-webkit-`. Just keep that in mind for whenever you write vendor-prefixed CSS.

I changed the timing for the function to a cubic bezier timing, which makes it look a little better in my opinion. The site I used to play around with the timings is made by Lea Verou, You can [use it](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.13,.38,.12,.97) to try some other timings.

Lastly, I changed the definitions from what you had before to:

```
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(0%);    }
    25%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);                 }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-225%); }
}
```

Above is just the `-webkit-` version to save space, but the others are just prefixed with the proper prefix. What I have done is told the animation to first rotate the ship, and then send it to its destination and rotate it back at the same time. The timing function makes it look like it goes very quickly at the beginning and more slowly at the end. If you wanted to delay the rotation for a little and have it starting moving before then, you just need to insert in some translation before it starts rotating, which is just a matter of inserting more breakpoints in the animation definition.

The final CSS is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/5GAX7/45/).

I hope that my answer helps explain everything I did. Have fun animating!

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! I think I'm gonna see what Dreamweaver CC has to offer. The build in css dev tool looks F***in awesome! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   @-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
       0% {
           -webkit-transform: scale(1) skew(0deg) translateX(0%);
       }
       50% {
           -webkit-transform: scale(1) skew(0deg) translateX(-225%) rotate(0deg) rotate(90deg) rotate(180deg);
       }
  100% {
           -webkit-transform: scale(1) skew(0deg) translateX(-225%);
       }
   }
```

I tried editing your code, I hope this would be a clue for you to moving further.

[jsfiddle edit](http://jsfiddle.net/5GAX7/9/)

also see the restart animation
[here](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)